# Looking for solution in case statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, case

I am trying to write this below statements in case statements. Trying to update a value in one different TableB for a particular column.

After I do

```
Update a 
set DISMMR =
```

then trying to check this below condition in case statements

```
'H01' Is not NULL 
  and
('H02','H03','HR04','S07','S08','S09') Is NULL
 Then 'Unknown'
```

Here this values are from table name : `TableA` and column name is `Code`.

This particular column is designed to be `NOT NULL`

Here where I say `Is NULL` means I am trying to say that, this particular value `('H02','H03','HR04','S07','S08','S09')` don't exist or present in `TableA`.

When I say this particular value `H01` in `TableA` for column `Code` ---- `Is not NULL` -- means this particular value of column `Code` exist/present in a column from `TableA`.

I need to do this one in case statements because once I am done checking this condition , I am writing other case statements started with **WHEN** to check another condition and update with different value

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2. Now I wrote the below query. It runs fine in SSMS but when i use this Store procedure in SSIS package. My package fails with error.

[Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "execute [dbo].[usp_GetMRF_CHP] ?,?,?" failed with the following error: "Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly

```
CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.TableA WHERE Code = 'H01')
  AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.TableA 
                 WHERE Code IN ('H02','H03','HR04','S07','S08','S09')
                )
 THEN 'Unknown'
when ---- I have another case here.
```

Any help will be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct you want to know if a record with Code = 'H01' exists while no record with the other codes exist. The case statement for that would look like this:

```
CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.TableA WHERE Code = 'H01')
      AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.TableA 
                     WHERE Code IN ('H02','H03','HR04','S07','S08','S09')
                    )
     THEN 'Unknown'
END
```